# Не отображается button (navbar-toggler) Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, button, hide

Проблема в том что пытался кастомизировать Навбар панельку и столкнулся с проблемой что в итоге пропала кнопка выпадающего списка при адаптивности. Перелопатил уже всю документацию пытался что то возвращать ничего не помогло.
Помогите плиз может что то упустил.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-primary">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <!-- ml-auto ml-right -->
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: PS. В песочнице под брендом невидимая кнопка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что в 4.0.0-alpha.6 привязка к кнопке `class="navbar-toggler"` через `.navbar-toggleable .navbar-toggler{` а не через `.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler{`

Поэтому добавьте в `<nav class="...` класс `navbar-toggleable`

Т.е. должно быть

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-primary navbar-toggleable">
```